# Wrong icmp cksum with go

Tags: go, checksum, icmp

Now I'm wrinting an ICMP message. When I send the icmp to 114.114.114.114, it said wrong icmp cksum. However, I send the same icmp to github, it was success. There is my code to calculate the checksum.

```
// CheckSum calculate the CheckSum of icmp
func CheckSum(data []byte) uint16 {
    var (
        sum    uint32
        length int = len(data)
        index  int
    )
    for length > 1 {
        sum += uint32(data[index])<<8 + uint32(data[index+1])
        index += 2
        length -= 2
    }
    if length > 0 {
        sum += uint32(data[index])
    }
    sum += sum >> 16

    return uint16(^sum)
}
```

and the icmp type is 8 and code is 0. How can I get the correct checksum and why it is only wrong when I send the message to 114.114.114.114?

Comment: Byte order might be wrong for iterating by 16 bits in `data`, try `sum += uint32(data[index+1])<<8 + uint32(data[index])`

Comment: I have try ''' sum += uint32(data[index+1])<<8 + uint32(data[index]) ''' but it is wrong and I cannot get any reply(7.7.7.7 and 114.114.114.114). I think it is not correct to calculate the checksum.

Comment: The checksum should include the ICMP type and code too, which you do outside of the posted code. Maybe the error is in that? Also check out this Go ICMP implementation: [`golang.org/x/net/icmp`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/net/+/c6fcb2db:icmp/message.go;drc=c6fcb2dbf98596caad8f56c0c398c1c6ff1fcff9;l=42)